# how can we get telerik drop down selection change event in grid view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, telerik

I am using telerik controls in my project, any body tell how to get selection change event in telerik grid view that can fill multiple column text boxes in insert, edit. that is in mvc3+razor(cshtml).

editor template code

```
@model string
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            @(Html.Telerik().ComboBoxFor(e => e)
               .BindTo(ViewBag.pro as SelectList)
               .ClientEvents(events => events.OnChange("getproductdesc")) )
        </td>

        <td>

        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.TextBoxFor((model => model), new { id = "textbox" })

        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function getproductdesc(e) {
       var idmodel = $(this).val();
       alert(idmodel);
       $('#textbox').val($(this).val());             
    }
</script>
```

grid view code

```
  @(Html.Telerik().Grid(Model)
    .Name("gdProductDetails")
    .ToolBar(commands => commands.Insert())
             .DataKeys(keys => keys.Add(c => c.Product_cd))
             .Pageable(paging =>
                    paging.PageSize(5)
                          .Style(GridPagerStyles.NextPreviousAndNumeric)
                          .Position(GridPagerPosition.Bottom))
                                   .Sortable(sorting => sorting
                    .SortMode(GridSortMode.MultipleColumn))
                    .DataBinding(databing => databing.Server()
                                      // .Select("DCProductDetails", "DeliveryChallan")
                                       .Insert("Addproduct", "DeliveryChallan")
                                       .Update("Editproduct", "DeliveryChallan")
                                       .Delete("Delete", "Home"))
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(c => c.Sl_no);/*EditorTemplateName("Product")*/
        columns.Bound(c => c.Product_cd).EditorTemplateName("product").Width(350);
        columns.Bound(c => c.Prouduc_desc).ClientTemplate("<input type='text' id='textbox'/>");        
        columns.Bound(c => c.Prod_rt);
columns.Command(commands =>
        {
            commands.Edit();
            commands.Delete();
        });
    })
  )  
</table>
</fieldset>
```

controller code

```
var listproduct = (from i in db.MSM_PRODUCT select i);
ViewBag.pro = new SelectList(listproduct, "PRODUCT_DESC", "PRODUCT_CD");
```

Comment: i fill my dropdown throw editor template, now i wrote onchange event in editor template only. the event is fired but i am not getting value at anoter column. it is working when i gave a text box at same editor template. so please help me in this problem.

Comment: You need to post code of what you have done so far

Comment: i added code which is i am using. at columns.Bound(c => c.Prouduc_desc).ClientTemplate("<input type='text' id='textbox'/>");  place i want to bind the data after selected the drop down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@model string
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            @(Html.Telerik().ComboBoxFor(e => e)
               .BindTo(ViewBag.pro as SelectList)
               .ClientEvents(events => events.OnChange("getproductdesc")) )
        </td>

        <td>

        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.TextBoxFor((model => model), new { id = "textbox" })

        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function getproductdesc(e) {
       var idmodel = $(this).val();
       alert(idmodel);
       $('#textbox').val($(this).val());             
    }
</script>
grid view code

  @(Html.Telerik().Grid(Model)
    .Name("gdProductDetails")
    .ToolBar(commands => commands.Insert())
             .DataKeys(keys => keys.Add(c => c.Product_cd))
             .Pageable(paging =>
                    paging.PageSize(5)
                          .Style(GridPagerStyles.NextPreviousAndNumeric)
                          .Position(GridPagerPosition.Bottom))
                                   .Sortable(sorting => sorting
                    .SortMode(GridSortMode.MultipleColumn))
                    .DataBinding(databing => databing.Server()
                                      // .Select("DCProductDetails", "DeliveryChallan")
                                       .Insert("Addproduct", "DeliveryChallan")
                                       .Update("Editproduct", "DeliveryChallan")
                                       .Delete("Delete", "Home"))
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(c => c.Sl_no);/*EditorTemplateName("Product")*/
        columns.Bound(c => c.Product_cd).EditorTemplateName("product").Width(350);
        columns.Bound(c => c.Prouduc_desc).EditorTemplateName("Product");
        columns.Bound(c => c.Prod_rt);
columns.Command(commands =>
        {
            commands.Edit();
            commands.Delete();
        });
    })
  )  
</table>
</fieldset>
```

function getproductdesc(e) {
       var idmodel = $(this).val();
       alert(idmodel);
       $('#textbox').val($(this).val());             
    }

create a editor template with a text box and id assign the editor template to appreciative column with view name, write jquery below  grid view, and assign the value like below   $('#textboxid').val($(this).val());